# Are there known pairs of simple numbers equal to huge precision, but not equal strictly?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, approximation

Are there known pairs of numbers $a$ and $b$, which at first look at them seemed likely to be equal, and after checking up to $10^n$ decimal places appeared to agree, but suddenly for some $n$ they would appear unequal?

Of course, I don't mean such things like $\arccos(-1+10^{-10000})\approx\pi$, which are clearly ad hoc and uninteresting. I mean something more like $\pi^4+\pi^5\approx e^6$ (which holds with relative error $\approx 4\times10^{-8}$), but would like to have some similarly simple approximate equality valid with relative error of $10^{-100}$ or even smaller.

Comment: How did you find the mentioned example ?

Comment: This xkcd comic comes to mind: https://xkcd.com/217/

Comment: @Peter googled for "unexpected approximate equalities", opened [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence)

Comment: $3487^{12}+4365^{12} \approx 4472^{12}$,  and this is from [Homer Simpson](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReOQ300AcSU)

Comment: @math137 These numbers differ even in most significant digit...

Comment: take the reciperocals

Comment: @math137 still $1.56\times10^{-44}$ vs $1.96\times 10^{-44}$. Not too close.

Comment: you are right, I was wrong, sorry

Comment: So $e^{\pi\sqrt {163}}$ is not good enough for you :(

Comment: @math137 To reveal Homer's genius rather compute $\sqrt[12]{3487^{12}+4365^{12}}\approx 4472.000000007$

Comment: @hagen but this is not "unexpected". There is a theory explaining why this number is nearly an integer.

Comment: PARI gives the following result : ? (3487^12+4365^12)^(1/12)
%6 = 4388.841178878421569355007603
? Is there a typo somewhere ?

Comment: ? (3987^12+4365^12)^(1/12)
%8 = 4472.000000007059290738213530
? So, 3487 must be replaced by 3987.

Comment: ? 3987^12+4365^12
%9 = 63976656349698612616236230953154487896987106
? 4472^12
%10 = 63976656348486725806862358322168575784124416
? Shows that a normal table calculator cannot distinguish these numbers. Related to the "near misses" concerning fermats equation $x^n + y^n = z^n$

Comment: A very nice example is also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral

Comment: You can find several examples in Chapter 10, titled "Danger! Always Exercise Caution When Using the Computer" in "The Computer As Crucible: An Introduction To Experimental Mathematics" by Jonathan Borwein and Keith Devlin.

Comment: A 42 billion digits coincidence: http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/~pborwein/SLIDES/COGNOS.pdf, p. 25.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It and its description is given in Borwein, Borwein "Strange Series and High Precision Fraud". But it's obviously no coincidence: $10^5$ and its square inside exponential is too similar to that $10^{-10000}$ in the example with $\arccos$ I gave in the question. If this number is enlarged (e.g. to $10^6$), we'd get even higher precision of coincidence (namely, 4.2 trillion digits).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer

Answer (score 1):

$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx 262\,537\,412\,640\,768\,744$ to 12 decimal places.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirement of relative error $\le10^{-100}$ though...